# identifying composite key in this table

Tags: mysql, database

I am having trouble identifying a composite key in this table.

[image]

I have selected `EmploeeNum` + `MAC` as primary key, and then `EmploeeNum` + `Type` as primary key, but according to my professor this is wrong because 3rd party softwares can be used to change the MAC address of the device, and according to him, the combination on `EmployeeNum` and `Device Model` should be the primary key.

How can `EmployeeNum` and `Device Model` be the primary key ?

**Edit:**
This information is also given with the table,

> Ms Tireless Worker (empl. No 115002) does not have any computers or
>   devices. The Cray Supercomputer (a PC) is on the approved list of
>   devices, but nobody has one

Comment: Yes Mac address will change when you updating or changing the device model.

Comment: @Strawberry, why not `EmployeeNo` and `Type` be the appropriate key ?

Comment: Can an employee have more than one PC, or more than one phone? Surname and firstname do NOT belong in this table.

Comment: @Strawberry, i have added additional details in the question. 
P.S: this is what I am confused about.."can employee have more than one PC/Phone ?" ..how someone would know that if it is not mentioned in the quesiton ?

Comment: On the assumption that each employee has no more than one phone, and no more than one PC (a not unreasonable assumption in a professional workplace) then (employeeno,type) would be a good PK. There would be no row for Ms Tireless Worker, but that's fine. This is not the employee table.

Comment: @Strawberry, so you meant that we have to identify the key based on our own assumptions ?

Comment: I have no idea what the assignment is nor what the expectations are. I'm merely stating that in a table that logs devices against employees, a PK formed on (emplyeeno,device_type) seems reasonable. We have already established that this table is poorly designed because it stores redundant data (firstname,surname).

Comment: @Strawberry yes the table is designed poorly.. better split up into two table.. pls post your requirement

Answer (score -1):

Yes Mac address will be change when you updating or changing the device model.. according to me  Employee No and Device Model should be primary key. based on device model MAC address will change.if you want you can update your MAC address but you can not change your device model.

Comment: according to strawberry  "has no more than one phone, and no more than one PC"

Comment: @ArulSidthan My comment was in reference to device type, not device model - I suppose it's not inconceivable that an employee's 'PC' is also their 'phone' !!